# Swift TimePicker Show Into UIAlerController with Cancel and Save Button Action

Tags: ios, swift

My Scenario, I am trying to show TimePicker (Only showing HH:MM and AM or PM) within `UIAlertController` with Cancel and Save Button action. I tried below code but Its not working.

```
let myDatePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    myDatePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    myDatePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: 270, height: 200)
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alertController.view.addSubview(myDatePicker)
    let selectAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { _ in
        print("Selected Date: \(myDatePicker.date)")
    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(selectAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion:{})
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed this issue by using below line

```
myDatePicker.datePickerMode = .time
```